How to get position of nodes(marker2d) in a gruop / GODOT 4.2.2
I would like to spawn "enemy" on the position of every marker2d. Those markers are in a group called "enemies". I would like to know if its possible to spawn an "enemy" on every marker by just looking at the group.
I tried almost every solution online and I failed. From creating a new function to just get the position of nodes in a group, to changing markers2d into other nodes, to creating new variables...
In short im trying to avoid defining vector2 for each marker2d or using $nodes everywhere. I would like to know if this is possible by just looking at groups.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This should be what you’re looking for:
for spawnpoint in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("enemies"):
    if spawnpoint is Marker2D:
        spawn_enemy(spawnpoint)

Or if your Marker2Ds expose the spawn_enemy() function you could do this:
get_tree().call_group("enemies", "spawn_enemy")

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/groups.html
Try this, maybe? You’re not going to need func spawn_enemy().
func _ready():
    for spawnpoint in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("enemies"):
        if spawnpoint is Marker2D:
            var enemy = enemy_scene.instantiate()
            main.add_child(enemy)
            enemy.position = spawnpoint.position


thank you for such a quick response which i wasnt expecting.

The debugger shows no errors however the game is stil spawning enemies in the position 0,0. Any further ideas?

Can you show the code you use to spawn?

Sure this is for the spawner (consisting of 2 markers2D)

[extends Node2D
var enemy_scene = preload("res://enemy.tscn")
@onready var main = get_node("/root/Main")
Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
for spawnpoint in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("enemies"):
if spawnpoint is Marker2D:
spawn_enemy()
func _on_timer_timeout():
var enemy = enemy_scene.instantiate()
main.add_child(enemy)
func spawn_enemy():
get_tree().call_group("enemies", "spawn_enemy")]

Sorry, I don’t really get it. You’re doing both ways I showed? Where are you setting the positions? I’m adding a suggestion to my answer

Yes, the only way it worked is if i did both things. Also do i need to set vectors for each marker(that i was trying to avoid)?

Thank you very much, the code works! I fixed it by removing the timer function(func _on_timer_timeout():) now it puts them exactly where the spawner is!
